# How to save/retrieve words to/from SQlite database?

Tags: android, sqlite, dictionary

Sorry if I repeat my question but I have still had no clues of what to do and how to deal with the question.

My app is a dictionary. I assume that users will need to add words that they want to memorise to a Favourite list. Thus, I created a *Favorite button* that works on two phases:

- short-click to save the currently-view word into the Favourite list;
- and long-click to view the Favourite list so that users can click on any words to look them up again.

I go for using a SQlite database to store the favourite words but I wonder how I can do this task. Specifically, my questions are:

1. Should I use the current dictionary SQLite database or create a new SQLite database to favorite words?
2. In each case, what codes do I have to write to cope with the mentioned task?

Could anyone there kindly help?

Here is the dictionary code:

---

```
package mydict.app;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.util.Log;

public class DictionaryEngine {
static final private String SQL_TAG = "[MyAppName - DictionaryEngine]";

private SQLiteDatabase mDB = null;

private String mDBName;
private String mDBPath;
//private String mDBExtension;
public ArrayList<String> lstCurrentWord = null;
public ArrayList<String> lstCurrentContent = null;
//public ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = null;

public DictionaryEngine()
{
    lstCurrentContent = new ArrayList<String>();
    lstCurrentWord = new ArrayList<String>();
}

public DictionaryEngine(String basePath, String dbName, String dbExtension)
{
    //mDBExtension = getResources().getString(R.string.dbExtension);
    //mDBExtension = dbExtension;
    lstCurrentContent = new ArrayList<String>();
    lstCurrentWord = new ArrayList<String>();

    this.setDatabaseFile(basePath, dbName, dbExtension);
}

public boolean setDatabaseFile(String basePath, String dbName, String dbExtension)
{
    if (mDB != null)
    {
        if (mDB.isOpen() == true) // Database is already opened
        {
            if (basePath.equals(mDBPath) && dbName.equals(mDBName)) // the opened database has the same name and path -> do nothing
            {
                Log.i(SQL_TAG, "Database is already opened!");
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                mDB.close();
            }
        }
    }

    String fullDbPath="";

    try
    {
        fullDbPath = basePath + dbName + "/" + dbName + dbExtension;
        mDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(fullDbPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE|SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS);
    }
    catch (SQLiteException ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        Log.i(SQL_TAG, "There is no valid dictionary database " + dbName +" at path " + basePath);
        return false; 
    }

    if (mDB == null)
    {
        return false;
    }

    this.mDBName = dbName;
    this.mDBPath = basePath;

    Log.i(SQL_TAG,"Database " + dbName + " is opened!");

    return true;
}

public void getWordList(String word)
{
    String query;
    // encode input
    String wordEncode = Utility.encodeContent(word);

    if (word.equals("") || word == null)
    {
        query = "SELECT id,word FROM " + mDBName + " LIMIT 0,15" ;
    }
    else
    {
        query = "SELECT id,word FROM " + mDBName + " WHERE  word >= '"+wordEncode+"' LIMIT 0,15";
    }
    //Log.i(SQL_TAG, "query = " + query);

    Cursor result = mDB.rawQuery(query,null);

    int indexWordColumn = result.getColumnIndex("Word");
    int indexContentColumn = result.getColumnIndex("Content");

    if (result != null)
    {
        int countRow=result.getCount();
        Log.i(SQL_TAG, "countRow = " + countRow);
        lstCurrentWord.clear();
        lstCurrentContent.clear();
        if (countRow >= 1)
        {
            result.moveToFirst();
            String strWord = Utility.decodeContent(result.getString(indexWordColumn));
            String strContent = Utility.decodeContent(result.getString(indexContentColumn));
            lstCurrentWord.add(0,strWord);
            lstCurrentContent.add(0,strContent);
            int i = 0;
            while (result.moveToNext()) 
            {
                strWord = Utility.decodeContent(result.getString(indexWordColumn));
                strContent = Utility.decodeContent(result.getString(indexContentColumn));
                lstCurrentWord.add(i,strWord);
                lstCurrentContent.add(i,strContent);
                i++;
            } 

        }

        result.close();
    }

}

public Cursor getCursorWordList(String word)
{
    String query;
    // encode input
    String wordEncode = Utility.encodeContent(word);

    if (word.equals("") || word == null)
    {
        query = "SELECT id,word FROM " + mDBName + " LIMIT 0,15" ;
    }
    else
    {
        query = "SELECT id,content,word FROM " + mDBName + " WHERE  word >= '"+wordEncode+"' LIMIT 0,15";
    }
    //Log.i(SQL_TAG, "query = " + query);

    Cursor result = mDB.rawQuery(query,null);

    return result;      
}

public Cursor getCursorContentFromId(int wordId)
{
    String query;
    // encode input
    if (wordId <= 0)
    {
        return null;
    }
    else
    {
        query = "SELECT id,content,word FROM " + mDBName + " WHERE Id = " + wordId ;
    }
    //Log.i(SQL_TAG, "query = " + query);
    Cursor result = mDB.rawQuery(query,null);

    return result;      
}

public Cursor getCursorContentFromWord(String word)
{
    String query;
    // encode input
    if (word == null || word.equals(""))
    {
        return null;
    }
    else
    {
        query = "SELECT id,content,word FROM " + mDBName + " WHERE word = '" + word + "' LIMIT 0,1";
    }
    //Log.i(SQL_TAG, "query = " + query);

    Cursor result = mDB.rawQuery(query,null);

    return result;      
}

public void closeDatabase()
{
    mDB.close();
}

public boolean isOpen()
{
    return mDB.isOpen();
}

public boolean isReadOnly()
{
    return mDB.isReadOnly();
}

}
```

And here is the code below the Favourite button to save to and load the Favourite list:

---

```
btnAddFavourite = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnAddFavourite);
btnAddFavourite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Add code here to save the favourite, e.g. in the db.
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(ContentView.this, R.string.messageWordAddedToFarvourite, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();
            }
        });

    btnAddFavourite.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

                // Open the favourite Activity, which in turn will fetch the saved favourites, to show them.
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FavViewFavourite.class);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent); 

                return false;
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: You don't need to create a new database, in my opinion you just need two queries, one to fetch all the favorites form the favorites table, and one to save a favorite into the table.

Comment: i strongly suggest you use DBAdaptor in android. Link: http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/40842/0/page/1

Comment: Many thanks. I'll try as you guys prompt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have two tables

1. words
2. favorites

Words(id, word, meaning,...)

Favorites(id, word_id)

In the Favorites table have a foreign key that points the word from the Words Table.

I have only addressed the way you need to structure the table.

****EDITED****

```
words(id, name, meaning, timestamp)
favortie(id, word_id)
```

Comment: @user998032 you need just one database which contains two tables as Harsha M V suggested.

Comment: Thank you very much. That's what I have been thinking of. But I do need an example to follow. Can you help?

Comment: share your present tables i will modify it for u

Comment: @Harsha M V: Thanks a lot, but sorry you meant the database? Here is my sample database: [link](http://www.mediafire.com/?ss1ebbktx4eva1e)

Comment: Thank you very much. I think I can use SQLite Browser to do this task. I'm following the link you provided to create a **DBAdapter class** but I can't really figure out how to store favourites to a new table in the existing SQLite db.

Comment: once u create a method like shown in the link.. all u will be doing is saveFav(wordID)